# How to fix 'Runtime Error '438' Object does not support this property or method' while trying to push a class into a collection within another class

Tags: excel, vba, stack

As the title says, I am getting errors when trying to push an object onto a stack. I've attached the classes and tester code below:

Tester:

```
Sub stackTest()
    Dim stackTest As cStack
    Dim testCollection As Collection

    Set stackTest = New cStack
    stackTest.init

    Set tester = New Collection
    Set curObj = New DVObject

    'curObj.Value = "hmm"
    tester.Add Item:=curObj
    stackTest.Push (curObj)

    curObj.Value = "nope"

    Debug.Print (Stack.Pop)

End Sub
```

Stack:

```
Option Explicit
Public pStack As Collection

' get item from stack.
Public Function Pop() As Variant
    With pStack
        If .Count > 0 Then
            If IsObject(.Item(.Count)) Then
                Set Pop = .Item(.Count)
            Else
                Pop = .Item(.Count)
            End If
            Pop = .Item(.Count)
            .Remove .Count
        End If
    End With
End Function

' add item to stack.
Public Sub Push(newItem As Variant)
    pStack.Add Item:=newItem
End Sub

' check if stack is empty.
Public Function isEmpty() As Boolean
    If pStack.Count = 0 Then isEmpty = True Else isEmpty = False
End Function

' initialize the stack.
Public Sub init()
    Set pStack = New Collection
End Sub
```

DVObject:

```
Option Explicit

Public name As Variant
Public Value As Variant
Public parent As DVObject
Public firstChild As DVObject
Public nextSibling As DVObject
```

I get the error on the line in the tester "stackTest.Push (curObj)"

This is weird because it seems to me like it should work based on the previous line where I add it to a tester collection.

I've tried changing the Push method in the cStack class to

```
Public Sub Push(ByVal newItem As Variant)
Public Sub Push(ByVal newItem As DVObject)
Public Sub Push(newItem As DVObject)
```

but nothing seems to be working. Can anyone point out my mistake? I've spent quite a while trying to fix this.

I've got very large text files (~500 gb) that I need to parse through. The stack is going to help me figure out what code blocks I am in.